# Regular expression to match first few characters repeated twice in string

Tags: r, regex, string, regular-language

I am facing an issue to find all strings which have **first few (>=2) characters** repeated **twice** in a string in R language.
E.g

*The strings should select out*
(1) **all**ochir**all**y ------> first 3 characters 'all' repeated twice in string
(2) **froufrou** ------> first 4 characters 'frou' repeated twice in string
(3) **under**gro**under** ------> first 5 characters 'under' repeated twice in string

*The strings should **NOT** select out*
(1) gummage ------> even first character 'g' repeated twice, but only 1 character, not match condition as >=2 first characters
(2) hypergoddess ------> no first few characters repeated twice
(3) kgashga ------> even 'ga' repeated twice, but not including the first character 'k', not match condition which require including the first character

Heard about `backreference` (e.g \b or \w) might be helpful, but still not able to figure out, could you help to figure out ?

Note: I see there is a function as `xmatch <- str_extract_all(x, regex) == x` as the method to use, the `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)`

```
x <- c("allochirally", "froufrou", "undergrounder", "gummage", "hypergoddess", "kgashga")
regex <- "as described details here"
function(x, regex) {
  xmatch <- str_extract_all(x, regex) == x
  matched_x <- x[xmatch]
}
```

If **very concise** would prefer!! Thanks

Comment: These seems to be part of the assignment.  Learn more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `grepl`:

```
x <- c("allochirally", "froufrou", "undergrounder", "gummage", "hypergoddess", "kgashga")
grepl("^(.{2,}).*\\1.*$", x)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The regex pattern matches and captures the first two or more characters, and then also asserts that the same two or more characters occur later in the string.

If you want to use the logic in my answer to obtain a *vector* of matching strings, then just use:

```
x[grepl("^(.{2,}).*\\1.*$", x)]

[1] "allochirally"  "froufrou"      "undergrounder"
```

Comment: Hi, Tim, thanks for quick response, just add one more important information, looks like it limited to use `str_extract_all` rather than `grepl`, for `grepl` you solution works, just try to use the pattern with 'str_extract_all', looks like not working for `str_extract_all(string, regex)`

Comment: @Lampard Can you include your call to `str_extract_all` ?

Comment: @Lampard - you probably don't want to use `str_extract_all()` as the pattern matches (or not) the entire length of the string.  Use `str_extract()` instead. If you want a logical value returned rather than the strings use `str_detect()`.

Comment: @Tim, update the detail with how the `str_extract_all` being called, your answer's `x` vector is exactly the same as what i used to test, the `regex` parameter is what discussed here

Comment: @Lampard Just a guess, but try: `str_extract_all(x, "(.{2,}).*\\1.*")` ... do _not_ use starting and ending anchors, as the API already applies the pattern to the entire string.

Comment: @H1, thanks to mention it, yeah, for a single string `str_detect` or `str_extract` is prefered as you mentioned, i have to work with a large group of strings, and need a vector return, so use `str_extract_all`

Comment: @ Tim, great, i have tried your updated solution, works wonderful, lovely thanks ! Vote up !

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^(\w{2,}).*?\1.*?$
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/4pYLIG/1)**

## Explanation:

The first capturing group `(\w{2,})` matches the initial few characters, and the backreference `\1` refers to this capturing group.

If needed later on, you can refer to the portion of characters repeated using group(1)

Comment: Hi, Robo, thank you for detail explain, your solution also works !